# React history.push doesn't navigate to the page even though the URL is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am on react 17.x and react-router-dom 5.2. After login, even though I do `history.push('/)`, it doesn't navigate to `/`. But the URL is updated in the address bar correctly.

**App.js:**

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import { isLoggedInServer } from "../src/utils/auth"
import history from "./utils/history"
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [isAuthed, setIsAuthed] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {

    if (typeof isAuthed === 'undefined') {
      isLoggedInServer().then(function (flag) {
        setIsAuthed(flag)
      });
    }
  }, [])

  if (typeof isAuthed === 'undefined') {
    return (
      <div>Please wait...</div>
    )
  }

  if (!isAuthed) {
    history.push('/login')
  }

  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <Dashboard setIsAuthed={setIsAuthed} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login setIsAuthed={setIsAuthed} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**history.js:**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**auth.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import api from "../utils/api"

export const login = () => {
  //to be written
}

export const logout = () => {
  // to be written
}

function isLoggedInServer() {
  let promise = api().get("/api/is-alive")
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      return true
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data.message)
      } else if (err.request) {
        // client never received a response, or request never left
      } else {
        // anything else
      }
      return false
    })
  return promise
}

export { isLoggedInServer }
```

**Login.jsx (signIn function)**

below function gets called when the 'Login' button is clicked.

```js
const signIn = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    api().get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
      api().post('/login', formInput).then(response => {
        if (response.data.error) {
          console.log(response.data.error)
        } else {
          login()
          console.log('routing to /')
          history.push('/') // <- this doesn't work
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        if (err.response) {
          setErr(err.response.data.message)
          console.log(err.response.data.message)
        } else if (err.request) {
          // client never received a response, or request never left
        } else {
          // anything else
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```js
import React from "react"

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>Dashboard</div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Comment: kindly share the code of DashBoard Component.

Comment: @UmairAnser It is just a simple code. I updated my question with the code of the `Dashboard.js`

Comment: put the attribute exact in app.js file like this

`<Route exact  path="/">
 <Dashboard setIsAuthed={setIsAuthed} />
 </Route>`

Comment: @UmairAnser I put it as you said, but nothing happens. Maybe I have done a fundamental mistake that I couldn't figure out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in app.js replace the return function with below code

```
 return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login setIsAuthed={setIsAuthed} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Dashboard setIsAuthed={setIsAuthed} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
```

Comment: It doesn't work... :( Login page is still displayed even though the address bar is updated

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to that you navigate too soon before all the routers are rendered. Try to move push inside useEffect. or use Redirect component from React Router

```html
useEffect(()=> {
  if (!isAuthed) {
    history.push('/login')
  }
}, [isAuthed]);
```

Comment: Thanks and I will check this and update (Y)